# Call ReadINI script using same one bat file

Tags: batch-file, ini

I need to use only one bat file, so I copied the script into my bat file. 
How can I call this script, and use the currval value in a local variable?

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set file=%1
set area=[%2]
set key=%3
set currarea=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (!file!) do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                echo !currval!
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are searching functions.

You could paste this into a batch file and call it via `call :myFunction`, but as batch functions haven't return values you need to do it explicitly by assigning the result to a variable.

In your case your code could look like this

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
call :myFunction %1 %2 %3
echo !result!
exit /b

:myFunction
set file=%1
set area=[%2]
set key=%3
set currarea=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (!file!) do (
    set ln=%%a
    if "x!ln:~0,1!"=="x[" (
        set currarea=!ln!
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in ("!ln!") do (
            set currkey=%%b
            set currval=%%c
            if "x!area!"=="x!currarea!" if "x!key!"=="x!currkey!" (
                set result=!currval!
            )
        )
    )
)
exit /b
```

Perhaps this doesn't fit perfectly, as it only takes one result, but I hope it points into the right direction.